# How can I add top border in lightning-tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I want to use CSS to add top border in my lightning tab. I know there is `--slds-c-tabs-item-color-border-active` to set the bottom border color but I don't find any to set the top border. I added it in CSS also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As possible variant :
You can create local **css file** and then upload it to your lwc as **static resource**

the **css file** will look like this :

```
.slds-tabs_default__item {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

So you need to import the static resource in your LWC :

```
import additonal_Resources from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Additonal_Resources';
```

And then upload in with [Platform Resource Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) , like this :

```
connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, additonal_Resources + '/my_css_file.css')
    ]).then(() => {
       // do something or not
    });
}
```